# Config Oracle database to disable Uppercase on tables and columns names

Tags: database, laravel, oracle

I'm using [Oracle DB Driver for Laravel](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8), I want to disable the uppercase on the table and column names.
According this [issue](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/105), I added this option to `config/database.php` as

```
options => [
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_UPPER,
]
```

To get the naturel names of tables and columns, but it still return names in uppercase

How can I disable the uppercase please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle, by default, stores all object names in uppercase. If you want to use mixed case, enclose everything into double quotes.

And - in my opinion - live rest of your Oracle life in misery.

Just in case you didn't get it: don't do that. You'll always have to use double quotes when referencing those object, and use exactly same letter case every time, making no mistakes.

Demo:

```
SQL> create table "DonTDoThat" ("my ID" number);

Table created.

SQL> select table_name from user_tables where upper(table_name) = 'DONTDOTHAT';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
DonTDoThat

SQL> select * From dontdothat;
select * From dontdothat
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * From DonTdoThat;
select * From DonTdoThat
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * From DONTDOTHAT;
select * From DONTDOTHAT
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * From "DonTDoThat";

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: 100% agree. Moreover, many tools for Oracle (even internal) doesn't support or support partially such names. So oracle standard upper-case will make your life easier with less troubles.